# Does anyone know where to find the area to edit this text

Tags: themes, wp-admin

At the very top of this site using Divi theme:

https://www.vmcalbany.org/new-home-2

Where it says "Register: Celebrating Our Heroes 2019" in white text on the blue strip.

Thanks!

Comment: It appears to be a menu. It will be in one of your menus in _Appearance > Menus_.

Answer (score 0):

It is a menu. 
Try to find it in the "edit menu" tab or in the "edit widgets" tab in the WP backend.

Regards Tom